# Getting [Product length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

New to programming iOS 7.. i am trying to create a search function from a sqlite database in xcode 5. I get this error and i cant figure out why. I used breakpoints and it narrowed it down to these 2 methods. how can i fix this?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
       return 1;
    }


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

    {
        if(tableView == self.tableView)
        {
            return self.products.count;
        }
        else
        {
            [self searchThroughData];
            return self.filteredProducts.count;
        } 
    }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
           static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }

            if(!cell)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

            }

            if (tableView == self.tableView) {
            cell.textLabel.text = self.products[indexPath.row];
            }
            else{
                cell.textLabel.text = self.filteredProducts[indexPath.row];
            }
            return cell;
        }
```

Comment: Please Google for "unrecognized selector" -- you will get literally thousands of hits.

Comment: Also, learn how to use the debugger and read exception dumps.  The exception stack dump will identify the exact failing line.

Comment: (Probably your error is here, or in a similar line: `cell.textLabel.text = self.products[indexPath.row];`)

Comment: (What kind of objects are stored in the `products` and `filteredProducts` arrays?)